# Does FAA have any info on army air corps pilots during wwII (know the FAA was formed later)?

Tags: military

Did the FAA (or its precursors) have any relationship to Army Air Corps pilots during WW2?  If so, how would I request information on my deceased father.  Most of his military records did not survive the fire in St. Louis.

Comment: Try ancestry.com. There may be some general information regarding his time in the service (WW2) that could prove helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, the FAA does not certify or track military pilots. The only records the FAA has or carried over from CAA would have is if he converted his hours for a certificate, but I would be surprised it would be anything more than a number.

Answer (score 1):

FAA does not.

Each military branch has many, many records, which are often well preserved but poorly sorted. They also have history offices, liaison offices, and many other offices besides which may have access to those records. There are also often amateur or professional historians who have information about a great many specific units.

You are more likely to get a good answer if you provide as much information as you know about your father's service here, and more likely to get a pointer to where to ask a government organization if you include even minimal information (What did he fly? Where? Did he mention any organization lower than the Army Air Corps? Who have you tried to contact? Did he show you any medals that might have public writeups? Etc)